# Android code does not update user account

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on an android code and trying to update the user information. I am able to retrieve the information but have not been able to update. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

In the if-else statement, it does not hit the If statement, goes directly to the error(else statement.

here is the code

```
package com.example.autrui;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.SendCallback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditPP extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editpp);
    final Button confirmChangeEditPP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bconfirmChangeEditPP);
    final EditText fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullName);
    final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);



    //final ParseUser currentUser = new ParseUser();
    final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    System.out.println(currentUser);
    String objectId = currentUser.getObjectId();
    System.out.println(objectId);
    String fName = currentUser.getString("fullName");
    fullName.setText(fName);
    email.setText(currentUser.getString("email"));

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> userQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    userQuery.getInBackground((String)objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){
      public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            confirmChangeEditPP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ParseACL acl = new ParseACL();
                    acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
                    acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
                    currentUser.setACL(acl);
                    object.put("fullName", fullName.getText().toString());
                    object.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                    object.saveInBackground();

                }
            });

        } else {
          Log.e("error","error");
        }
      }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    // Go to settings
    /*
     * if(MainActivity.s.isEmpty()) return; else { View v =
     * MainActivity.s.pop(); Class c = MainActivity.s2.pop(); Intent intent
     * = new Intent(v.getContext(), c); startActivityForResult(intent, 0); }
     */
}

private void showUserDetailsActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: So, what is the error you are getting then?

Comment: Why are you creating a query to fetch a User object that you already have? ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); gets the same object you are trying to query for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. the error was regarding the ACL and yes we did not need the query. I wrote the whole code again and made it simpler.

Comment: hi can you please show me how to update user class for specific objectid

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        // Retrieve the object by id
        query.getInBackground("o2JOQNlIaV", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                  ;

                    object.put("dateofbirth", "09/10/89");

                    object.saveInBackground();
                }
            }
        });
data is not updating into User class